How to clone entire drive of 2018 MacBook Pro?
I have a 2018 MacBook Pro I borrowed and need to return. I already have a cloud backup but wanted a full disk clone for extra safety. All my attempts are done in Recovery Mode.
I first tried to clone the whole disk using hdiutil create -srcdevice /dev/disk0 -format UDZO -o /Volumes/ExternalDrive/disk0.dmg. I have an 80 GB file (the SSD was 1 TB and quite full of data), so I know something was wrong. When I attached it, I just got an empty image.
/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk10
   1:                       0xEE ⁨⁩                        125.1 GB   disk10s1
                    (free space)                         875.5 GB   -

I then tried to clone the APFS synthesized disk. It seemed to work, but the volumes are encrypted and I don't know how to decrypt them. On the 2018 MacBook, I have:
+-- Container disk3 AD3E4EE4-1440-468C-9CA5-677DE00BC5A8
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk3
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      1000240963584 B (1.0 TB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   733871874048 B (733.9 GB) (73.4% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       266369089536 B (266.4 GB) (26.6% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 7000BE2B-1932-4836-83BD-41644636ED43
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       1000240963584 B (1.0 TB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk3s1 5220F233-F35B-4AAD-A056-41DA26FFB5EE
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s1 (Data)
|   |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - 数据 (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         721904885760 B (721.9 GB)
|   |   Sealed:                    No
|   |   FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk3s2 1578E60E-1F24-42F4-81D6-B14C53D1D51A
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s2 (Preboot)
|   |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         1775439872 B (1.8 GB)
|   |   Sealed:                    No
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk3s3 CB271A30-7E14-4CE5-9AF2-AEDE35166F74
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s3 (Recovery)
|   |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         1116946432 B (1.1 GB)
|   |   Sealed:                    No
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk3s4 4EE2238A-AD9A-4030-BFFB-42A03E737CD6
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s4 (System)
|   |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         8865898496 B (8.9 GB)
|   |   Sealed:                    Broken
|   |   FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk3s6 CDCF8CA7-0DAC-41A2-AB14-8D5458E159E4
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s6 (VM)
|       Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|       Capacity Consumed:         20480 B (20.5 KB)
|       Sealed:                    No
|       FileVault:                 No
|

but for the disk image:
/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +1.0 TB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk12
                                 Physical Store disk11
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - 数据⁩     721.9 GB   disk12s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 1.8 GB     disk12s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk12s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            8.9 GB     disk12s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      20.5 KB    disk12s6

+-- Container disk12 AD3E4EE4-1440-468C-9CA5-677DE00BC5A8
    =====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk12
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      1000240963584 B (1.0 TB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   733871874048 B (733.9 GB) (73.4% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       266369089536 B (266.4 GB) (26.6% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk11 (No UUID)
    |   -------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk11
    |   Size:                       1000240963584 B (1.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk12s1 5220F233-F35B-4AAD-A056-41DA26FFB5EE
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk12s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - 数据 (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         721904885760 B (721.9 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Locked)
    |
    +-> Volume disk12s2 1578E60E-1F24-42F4-81D6-B14C53D1D51A
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk12s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1775439872 B (1.8 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk12s3 CB271A30-7E14-4CE5-9AF2-AEDE35166F74
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk12s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1116946432 B (1.1 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk12s4 4EE2238A-AD9A-4030-BFFB-42A03E737CD6
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk12s4 (System)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         8865898496 B (8.9 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    Broken
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Locked)
    |   Encrypted:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk12s6 CDCF8CA7-0DAC-41A2-AB14-8D5458E159E4
        ----------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk12s6 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               Not Mounted
        Capacity Consumed:         20480 B (20.5 KB)
        Sealed:                    No
        FileVault:                 No

I tried various things on both the 2018 borrowed Mac and my new MacBook, but I couldn't figure out what the problem was:
jin@Joy-MBP ~ [1]> diskutil apfs listcryptousers /dev/disk12s1
No cryptographic users for disk12s1

jin@Joy-MBP ~> diskutil apfs unlockVolume disk12s1 -user disk
Passphrase:
Unlocking the "disk" cryptographic user on APFS Volume disk11s1
User does not exist; try "diskutil apfs listCryptoUsers"

What should I try next?

You only need to copy the "Data" volume. I'd recommend using SuperDuper! or CarbonCopyCloner.

Yes, SuperDuper! is highly recommended, have used to clone macOS drives for years. That or CCC will make your life significantly easier here.
